# Need OSX code to process audio stream of an .m4v movie file

Tags: macos, audio, extract, m4v

I need to process the audio stream of an .m4v movie file?

Can anyone get me started?

This is my first go at an osx project,  up till now I've only done iOS

( specifically I need to examine the audio stream for a beep, which is well defined.   if I can get the audio stream as a bunch of floats or ints I should be able to extract it  without too much trouble )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is plenty of [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code) for working with audio at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/).

Comment: obviously...  how about something helpful? :)

Comment: Click on the above link (which takes you to the Mac OS X sample code on http://developer.apple.com) and type "audio" in the search box - that will show you all the audio-related sample code.

Comment: Thanks!   I found some sample code that did pretty much exactly what I needed, http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/QTExtractAndConvertToAIFF/Introduction/Intro.html and led me to: http://developer.apple.com/quicktime/audioextraction.html  Sorry,  I thought you were just linking me to Apple's homepage.

Comment: @Ohmu: no problem: I've now updated my answer to hopefully make the purpose of the links clearer.